# add CSS element using an angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Im using angular and ng-repeat to populate a list of studies. This list is dynamic so you can toggle into child elements of each element. So basically I have a accordion style toggle list that can go three levels deep on each list item. I have a jQuery issue that I think should be solved with some angular directive or something. Basically I have an arrow (glyphicon) that should switch to up or down depending on if your looking at a child or a parent element in this list. I have this working with pure jQuery just adding and removing a css class from each list item. However, it only works on the first item in the list because ng-repeat creates multiple id’s but jQuery will only work on the first element with that id tag.

This is the HTML from the page.

```
<!-- User Studies List -->
<div ng-controller="StudiesController" id="before">
    <h3 class="center"> User Studies </h3>
    <div ng-repeat="study in studies" arrow>
        <div class="panel-group" style="margin-bottom:0">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{$index}}">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">{{ study.study }} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right"></span></h3>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse{{$index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{study.id}}" style="margin-left:1%" id="sampleID{{$index}}">
                            <i>Sample: </i>{{ study.sample }}
                            <span id="glyph-switch" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right"></span>
                            <span id="glyph-up" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up pull-right"></span>
                        </li>
                        <div id="collapse{{study.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin-left:3%"><i>Fastq: </i>{{ study.fastq }}
                                    <div class="dropdown center pull-right">
                                        <button class="btn-xs btn-default hvr-shadow" id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                            Action <span class="caret"></span>
                                        </button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                                            <li id="list-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#more-metadata-modal" ng-click="showMore(study)">More Data</li>
                                            <li id="list-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-metadata-modal" ng-click="showMore(study)">Edit</li>
                                            <li id="list-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-metadata-modal" ng-click="showMore(study)">Delete</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Javascript

```
var count = 1;
$(document).on("click", "li[id*='sampleID']", function() {
    console.log("clicked");
    if(count > 0) {
        $('#glyph-switch').css('visibility','hidden');
        $('#glyph-up').css('visibility', 'visible');
        count -= 1;
        console.log("count", count);
    } else {
        $('#glyph-switch').css('visibility','visible');
        $('#glyph-up').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        count += 1;
        console.log("count",count);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use angular code (no jQuery at all).

Since you already have an object of studies, just handle an `onClick="showGlyph($index)"` passing the index and then in the code just set the a state for the up/down arrow `$scope.GlyphUp = !$scope.GlyphUp`.

In the template file have the up/down arrow object bind `ng-show="GlyphUp"`

Comment: Add change of class based on the values of your object https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: @9ers Rule, the 9ers suck bro. but thanks for your help I figured it out with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/